# jQuery .change() not triggering on select - example from api.jquery.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

I copied this example from api.jquery.com

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

I also tried:

```
$('#target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

I copied it into my .js file, which is included in my html. I have another jQuery function in there (beginning $(window).load(function () { ..."

The other function is working. But the above simple function is not.

The form looks like this:

```
<form>
    <select id="target" class="target">
        <option name="pp" value="6">6</option>
        <option name="pp" value="12">12</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```

I want to just use id, but I added class just for testing. But neither works.

Why doesn't this simple function work? Do I need to do anything else to connect the change event to the function? I am new to jQuery, but I know that in javascript I would have to have the onchange event of the form call the function in order for something to happen.

EDIT: Ok, here is EVERYTHING in my included .js file. As you can see, just one other function. Is it interfering?
Also, I have only 1 form on the page, which you see above. I am going to have it change the number of results shown per page (6 or 12).

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("img.gall_img").each(function() { // iterate through all img of class gall_img
        var imgWidth = $(this).width(); // "$(this)" to access jQuery width() func
        var divWidth = $(this).closest('div').width();
        //alert(imgWidth + " and " + divWidth); // for debugging
        if(imgWidth > divWidth) {
            var position = Math.round(-1 * ((imgWidth/2) - (divWidth/2))); // 
            position = position + "px"; // make position format "123px".
                $(this).css("left", position); // "$(this)" to access jQuery css() func
            }
    });
});


$("#target").change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Comment: Is the handler bound after `DOMReady`?

Comment: you should uplaod the complete code

Comment: what browser version you use ?

Comment: To expand upon David Hedlund's comment, is the `change` event handler inside your `$(window).load` function? If not, that's your problem - the `select` element doesn't exist when the event is bound.

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct (James Allardice and David Hedlund). So, when my function is outside of $(window).load or $(document).ready then it is parsed and tossed out as garbage because the DOM hasn't been downloaded yet? Is that correct? In that case, I assume that nearly all functions must be placed inside one of those two I listed above.

Comment: @ButtleButkus - Yes, any function that interacts with the DOM will have to be called after the DOM has loaded. In this case, the `change` function will be called on the jQuery object which you expect to contain `#target`, but actually contains no elements (since `#target` didn't exist at the time) so nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the code **inside** the `$(window).load` function, like so:

```
$(window).load(function () {

//whatever code is already here

$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});

}); //end of $(window).load function
```

`$(window).load(function ()` tells the browser to only run that code after the entire page is loaded INCLUDING images. Traditionally with jQuery you will see the `$(document).ready(function() {`... which tells the browser to not process that code until after the page is loaded (not including images)

IF you don't need to wait for the images to load to run your jQuery then you could replace `$(window).load(function () {` with `$(document).ready(function () {`

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could I also optionally add a separate $(document).ready and put the rest of my functions in there? Is it possible to have both that and the $(window).load together on one page? I need $(window).load for my image-adjusting function (see my edited question).

Comment: you could because $(window).load is the equivalent of onLoad whereas $(document).ready is specific to jQuery - but it usually isn't necessary. In general only use $(window).load if you need to wait for the entire page (e.g. images) to load before processing your code. For 99% of cases $(document).ready is perfectly fine.

Comment: I kept $(window).load for my image function, and created a separate section with $(document).ready and now the .change() works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your `.change(..)` inside a `.ready(..)` function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#target').change(function() {
    alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code in jsFiddle => http://jsfiddle.net/GjScg/

And this code should work, is there any other javascript that is bounded on the Change event? Perhaps there's some other code around, that causes errors?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, it doesn't work?
Here is a working link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/7pEP4/

**UPDATE:**

Both versions work: http://jsfiddle.net/ayezutov/7pEP4/1/

Comment: "Are you sure, it doesn't work?" - it is pretty easy to tell if an alert window is popping up. jsfiddle auto-wraps the js in a $(document).ready type function, which is why it works in jsfiddle.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. There were enough answers right after my post, which pointed to that, so i didn't update it ;)